# Does starter replacement make sense in a heat sink situation?

Tags: replace, starter, heat, gmc

Related to: [Slow chugs from starter with warm engine but not cool engine?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/5434/slow-chugs-from-starter-with-warm-engine-but-not-cool-engine)

It seems that while the engine is running, it heats up the starter, and then it sounds like it is barely able to start.

This is the factory starter, and there appears to be a factory heat shield in place.

I have read that older starters require additional power / are less efficient.

So it seems that rather than installing after-market insulation, I should get the starter replaced - after all, it is 14 years old.

Does this seem like a good idea to you, or do you think that the new starter would have the same problem the old one did?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking the starter out and bring it to your local  auto parts store. Most can test it to verify it is bad. There is the oddball chance that the engine may be overheating and something is binding internally.  While installing the new starter verify that the heat shield is intact and that the battery cables are clean tight and in good shape. Also make sure you save and reuse any shims(thin metal strips that fit between the starter and block) that your current starter is using.